# How do I swap specific substring in specific location without using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

Implement function ion2e() that takes a string as input and returns a copy of the word back with the following change: if the entered word ends in 'ion', then 'ion' is replaced with 'e'
The function should only replace the 'ion' with 'e' when the 'ion is at the end of the string.

> input:'congratulations'

> output:'congratulate'

> input:'ionization'

> output:'ionizate'(this word does not exist but I made it up as an example)

Here is the code using regex:

```
 import re 
 def ion2e(word):
    return re.sub('ion$','e',word)
```

and here is the code I made in the beginning:

```
def ion2e(word):
    if word[-3:-1]=='ion':
        return word.replace('ion','e')
```

The code I made does not work at all. I am wondering maybe there is improvement I can make on my code or I have started it at the wrong direction? Is there way to do the question without using regex?

Comment: try, ``re.sub('ion\w?$', 'e', word)`` ?

Comment: I would say `re.sub(r'ions?$', 'e', word)`

Comment: sorry I didnt mention it clearly. That code with regex works fine and it is a correct answer. I just want to know if there is way to do it without using the regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When debugging code, it often helps to print out intermediate results. In your second `ion2e` function, you check `word[-3:-1]`. See what happens when you run that with one of your inputs:

```py
>>> word = 'ionization'
>>> word[-3:-1]
'io'
```

That is because the second number in your slicing expression `-1` (referring to the last letter) is *not* included in the slice. Instead, use `word[-3:]` to get the last three letters.

```py
>>> word = 'ionization'
>>> word[-3:]
'ion'
```

However, there is another problem: `str.replace()` will return a copy with *all* occurrences replaced (see documention: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```py
>>> word.replace('ion', 'e')
'eizate'
```

You will have to make the replacement smarter.

Comment: Does it mean involving regex is the only way to make it only replace at my desired position?

Comment: no, you just have to make sure to only replace the last occurrence

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
import re
def ion2e(word):
    return re.sub('ion$', 'e', word[:-1]) if word[-1] == 's' else re.sub('ion$', 'e', word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have figured out how to do it without using regex:
here is the code:

```
def ion2e(word):
    if word[-3:]=='ion':
        return word[:-3]+'e'
    return word
```